# Refactoring code to use epoll instead of signal handlers

Tags: c, signals, epoll, mkfifo

I have some very basic code, here that creates two **NAMED** pipes, one for a handler and another for an execuetor.

Now I have a partially implemented signal handler, that handles signals from the pipes

How would I go about refactoring this  to use epoll instead of traditional signal handlers.

Do I need signal handlers if I have used epoll?

```
void exchange_signal_handler(int signo);

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Not enough arguments\n");
        return 1;
    }



    char handler[100];
    char exec[100];


    sprintf(handler, "/tmp/handler_%s", argv[1]);
    sprintf(exec, "/tmp/execuetor_%s", argv[1]);


    int fd1 = open(handler,O_RDWR);
    int fd2 = open(exec,O_RDWR);


    if (signal(SIGINT, exchange_signal_handler) == SIG_ERR) {
        printf("Unable to register exchange signal handler\n");
        return 1;
    }

    

}


void exchange_signal_handler(int signo) {
    printf("Received signal %d from exchange with data: %s\n", signo);
}
```

For example, how would I refactor so that my code uses the epoll api, to listen for SIGUSR1 signal from the handler. And then write a message (lets say "Hello World") to the exec pipe after a SIGUSR1 is received from handler?

Comment: [Using signalfd and pidfd to make signals less painful under Linux](https://unixism.net/2021/02/making-signals-less-painful-under-linux/)